# Understanding groovy closures

Tags: groovy, closures

I am trying to understand how the resolution of Groovy's closure is being done in below code,

```
foo {
    a=10
    b=20
}

def foo(Closure closure) {
    def params = [:]

    closure.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    closure.delegate = params

    closure()

    println params.a
    println params.b
}
```

In the implementation of foo, the value is never assigned to `params`, then how come `params` get the values for `a` & `b`

I have read about Groovy closure but couldn't really get as to how this works???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following line defines property and method resolve strategy for closure [DELEGATE_FIRST](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/Closure.html#DELEGATE_FIRST). that means to get/set/call any property/method it will go to `delegate` object first and when there is no such property/method it will go to `owner` object.

```
closure.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
```

and the next line sets `delegate` object of the closure to `params`

```
closure.delegate = params
```

and finally your closure just sets two properties. and those properties set on `delegate` object (the `param` at this moment)

```
{
    a=10
    b=20
}
```

Comment: Does `DELEGATE_FIRST` also sets the property for delegate? I am aware of get for property but now aware of setting the property too?
Isn't this a side-effect?
The resolve strategy DELEGATE_FIRST means that it will try to resolve the property from DELEGATE first and then the owner.

Comment: @Aditya, i'v added details to answer. and yes, get/set/call in case of DELEGATE_FIRST will go to delegate object first and then to owner. that's not side effect - all according to [documentation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/Closure.html#DELEGATE_FIRST).